# Самый простой способ передачи большого количества параметров в Java

Tags: java, typescript, typescript-типы

Мой основной язык - TypeScript, и он позволяет упаковывать большое количество аргументов в объекты:

```
function initializeApplication(options: {
  projectBuildingMode: string,
  enableDebugging: boolean,
  projectType: string,
  // ... и ещё несколько десятков
}): void { }
```

Что есть в Java максимально близкое по концепции к приведённому выше коду?

### Проблема

```
void initializeApplication(String projectBuildingMode, Boolean enableDebugging, String projectType, /* и ещё пару десятков ... */)
```

Что, если мы заходим добавить в середину один-два параметра? Придётся переписывать места вызова этого метода.

Comment: нет здесь никакой проблемы. java - не скриптовый язык. посмотрите на это с точки зрения ооп. если вы хотите передать большое количество параметров в метод, то у вас явные проблемы с архитектурой приложения. почитайте GRASP. у вас есть классы, описывающие вашу предметную область. для работы с полями в пределах класса есть методы. сколько бы не было полей в классе, пердавать их никуда не надо, потому как методы класса и так имеют к ним доступ и могут их изменять. а если вы эти поля на обработку пердаете в другой класс, то вы явно нарушаете все, что только можно нарушить.

Comment: @Дмитрий, Благодарю Вас за комментарий. "Сколько бы не было полей в классе, передавать их никуда не надо" - ну, например, пользователь в нативном Java-приложении вводит данные человека - имя, фамилию, под, возраст, и так далее, и нам на основе этих введённых данных нужно будет создать экземпляр класса `Person` с соответствующими полями классов. Как в данном случае избежать того, чтобы передавать все эти данные в конструктор?

Comment: это совершенно другой вопрос. этот вопрос о создании экземпляра класса ,а не о передаче параметров.  разумеется, использовать конструктор на 50 параметров не стоит. в целом для того, чтобы создать экземпляр класса существуют порождающие паттерны.  в этом конкретном случае действительно проще всего использовать билдер. но даже без билдера вы можете создать экземпляр класса, используя конструктор без параметров, после чего с помощью сеттеров проинициализировать нужные поля.

Answer (score 4):

Вы можете создать класс который можно использовать в качестве аргумента и в случае добавления полей, вам нужно будет изменять только его, если вам не нужно будет модифицировать под новые поля другие функции, то при помощи конструкторов, значений по умолчанию и get/set вы можете избежать переписывания старых кусков.

Comment: Кратко - вы предлагаете использовать билдеры

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать использовать @Builder от ломбока, как подсказал @Miron или воспользоваться перечислением с помощью type... Ниже привел пример кода

```
@Builder
@ToString
public class Animal {
    private String cat;
    private String dog;
    private String cow;
    private String giraffe;
    private String bear;
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal animal = Animal
                .builder()
                .bear("Медведь")
                .cat("Мурка")
                .dog("Шарик")
                .build();
        printAnimal(animal);

        printAnimal("Медведь", " Кот", " Бык");
    }

    private static void printAnimal(Animal animal) {
        System.out.println(animal.toString());
    }

    private static void printAnimal(String... value) {
        Stream.of(value).forEach(System.out::print);
    }
}
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ. "Перечисление" - Вы имели ввиду Enum?

Answer (score 1):

На основе подсказок @Дмитрий, @IvanDyominov и @Miron разработал такой билдер:

```java
public class Person {

  private String familyName;
  private String givenName;


  public Person(ParametersObject parametersObject) {
    parametersObject.initializeSpecifiedFields(this);
  }


  public static ParametersObject parametersObject() {
    return new Person.ParametersObject();
  }


  public static class ParametersObject {

    private String familyName;
    private String givenName;


    public void initializeSpecifiedFields(Person person) {
      person.familyName = this.familyName;
      person.givenName = this.givenName;
    }


    public ParametersObject setFamilyName(String familyName) {
      this.familyName = familyName;
      return this;
    }

    public ParametersObject setGivenName(String givenName) {
      this.givenName = givenName;
      return this;
    }
  }
}
```

Теперь конструировать Person можно так:

```java
new Person(Person.parametersObject()
  .setFamilyName("Jonson")
  .setGivenName("John")
);
```

### Недостатки решения

1. Пока не знаю, как обязать других программистов, которые будут создавать инстанс `Person`, инициализировать обязательные поля. В теории, если можно как-то обязать вызвать метод, то проблема решаема.
2. Если понадобится облепить класс Person сеттерами, то они могут быть один в один с сеттерами с `ParametersObject` (если мы пожелаем цепную API). Разница лишь в том, что они возвращают разный `this`. Создавать абстрактный класс, общий для `Person` и `ParametersObject` не хочется - хотелось бы, чтобы всё было инкапсулировано в одном классе (то есть, чтобы сущность Person была основополагающей и самостоятельной).

*Конструктивная* критика решения приветствуется!